# Is there some other meaning in 微笑是一种真实的、热诚的、发自内心的快乐的情绪。?

Tags: meaning

> 微笑是一种真实的、热诚的、发自内心的快乐的情绪。

Take away the descriptive elements and it says:

微笑是情绪。 （A) smile is (a) mood.

Maybe if they said: ‘一个微笑表示着一种真实的、热诚的、发自内心的快乐的情绪。’ Would that be acceptable??

A smile is an expression of a mood, but not a mood in itself. I have to think of these lines from a song: 'I smile when I'm angry, I cheat and I lie, I do what I have to do to get by.'

Am I missing some meaning here?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, "微笑" (smile) is an "expression" (**表情**) not a "mood"(情绪)

"happy" (愉快/快乐) is a mood.

- 一个微笑 (A smile)
- 代表 (represents)
- 一个愉快的心情 (a happy mood)

> "微笑是一种真实的、热诚的、发自内心的快乐的情绪。"

should be

"微笑(**代表着**)一种真实、热诚、发自内心的快乐情绪。"

(you can omit most of the '的' to make it less wordy)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, this is a bad sentence.

You could short to “微笑是个*****情绪". It doesn't make sense.

And what @TangHo added make the whole logic right.

Or we could break this sentence down into 2 sentence:
"The emotion that make people smile"
"And this emotional is .............." -Definition of this emotion

Answer (score 1):

- 微笑[wēi xiào]   smile:1. a sweet smile; 甜蜜的微笑   2. friendly service; smiling service; 微笑服务
- 情绪[qíng xù]   1. （心理状态） mood; sentiments; morale; feeling: antagonistic sentiments; 对立情绪。rashness; 急躁情绪。

  2. （不愉快的情感） depression; moodiness; sulks:
     be in a fit of depression; be in low spirits; have a fit of the sulks; 闹情绪
     rather sulky; 有点儿情绪。
     3.(心理) emotion: Emotion swells and subsides. 情绪忽高忽低。